# Move staged changes to new branch and commit

Tags: git, branch, commit

On Git, I have currently some staged but uncommitted changes on the `master` branch.

Instead of committing to the master branch, I want to

1. create a new branch, say `development`; then
2. move the staged changes across to the new branch, and `reset`/clear the staged changes on `master`; then
3. commit the staged changes on the new branch; then
4. push commit to remote repo; then
5. merge this commit from `development` to the `master` on remote, and keep the `development` branch; then
6. refresh the local `master` from remote `master`, without changing my existing uncommitted files on local

May I ask how I should do that? I am still a beginner of git, so **please** explain in small steps so I can follow.

Note1: My staged change consists of more than 100 files, so it would be a pain to hand-pick and manually `add` them one by one to the new branch. I am trying to avoid this error-prone way if possible.

Note2: There are over 30 files which I have not staged the changes. I want to keep these changes locally even after I get a refresh from the remote `master`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## TL;DR

Changes are not staged "on a branch".  In fact, Git doesn't have *changes* at all: Git only has *snapshots*.

What does this mean?  Well, it means the short answer to your question is:

- create the new branch name (`git branch`); then
- switch to the new branch name (`git switch` or `git checkout`); then
- commit (`git commit`).

You can combine the first two steps with `git switch -c development` or `git checkout -b development`.  Both commands do the same thing: `git switch` was new in Git 2.23, as part of a project to split the overloaded `git checkout` command into two separate commands; the old `git checkout` remains in Git and probably will for the next 20 years, but it's a good idea to slowly migrate yourself to the new ones.

It's important to realize that this process—`git switch -c development` in particular—makes use of a short-cut.  It won't work for certain other cases, but it will work for *this* case.

## Longer

This really deserves a longer explanation though.  *Why* does the above work?  What you need to know starts with this:

#### Git is all about commits

Newbies to Git often think that Git is about files, which is natural enough: we store files in Git.  Or, they might think Git is about branches, which is also natural enough: we're always "on" some branch—as in, `git status` says `on branch master` or whatever.  Technically, you can also be on *no* branch, in what Git calls "detached HEAD mode", but except for some special cases, you don't normally want to work that way.

The thing is, neither of these views is right.  Git is, in the end, all about *commits*.  It's true that each commit *stores* files, and it's true that we form our commits into branches, that we also find with branches—or more precisely, with branch *names*, which we (rather sloppily / lazily) call branches even though we call other things branches too.  But in the end, Git is about the *commits*.

(Note: If you're getting a sense of there being something wrong when we use branches to find branches, you're on the right track: there *is* something wrong with this notion.  It's the fact that the word *branch* is badly defined.  It's (ab)used for multiple things.)

A repository is, at its heart, a collection of commits, plus a few other things we'll get to in a moment.  These commits are one of four kinds of Git *objects*, and Git stores all these objects in a big [key-value database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database), the *objects database*, which uses hash IDs (or more formally *object IDs* or OIDs) as the keys.  Git desperately needs these object IDs in order to *find* the commits in the database.

These hash IDs are big, ugly, and random-looking.  For instance, [<sup><sub>`9bf691b78cf906751e65d65ba0c6ffdcd9a5a12c`</sub></sup>](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9bf691b78cf906751e65d65ba0c6ffdcd9a5a12c) is a particular commit in any clone of the Git repository for Git itself.  *Every commit gets a unique hash ID:* all Git software everywhere in the universe agrees that that `9bf691...blahblah` thing means *that* commit, even if this particular repository never has had that commit and won't ever get it.  Git makes up a new *unique* hash ID every time you make a commit.<sup>1</sup>  This means that all you need to *find* the commit is the hash ID—but again, Git really *needs* that hash ID, so that it can look in its objects database.  Either it has that object, so it has the commit, or it doesn't.  If your Git repository lacks the commit, you'll need to *get* the commit from some repository that has it.  We'll leave out the details, but this is what `git fetch` is about.

Anyway, given that the commit is so important, you'll need to know exactly what a commit is and does for you.  So, besides the weird random-looking "number" (hash ID), here's what you need to know:

- Every commit is read-only.  The numbering system requires this.
- Every commit contains (indirectly) *every file*.  More precisely, a commit has a *full snapshot* of every file (that it has), as a sort of archive: a tarball or zip file or WinRAR or whatever, of your source files.  Git stores these very cleverly—including *de-duplicating* the contents—so that the contents get *shared* across, and even within, the commits, so even though every commit has every file, most commits are truly *tiny*.  The first one ever, in a new repository, isn't, since that one has to store all the files for the first time, but after that, most commits mostly re-use most files, so those re-used files take no space.
- Besides the snapshot, each commit contains some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.  This includes the name and email address of the person who made the commit, for instance.

Except for your name and email address (which Git gets from your `user.name` and `user.email` settings), Git mostly builds all the metadata on its own.  You just run `git commit` and Git makes a snapshot—we'll see "from where" in a moment—and adds on the metadata.  One of the most important pieces of metadata in any one commit, for Git, is a *list of previous commit hash IDs*.  Most commits have exactly one entry in this list: we call these "ordinary" commits.

This single previous commit hash ID, stored in an ordinary commit's metadata, makes the commit "point to" its *parent*.  That is, the commit remembers which commit comes *before* this particular commit.  If we like—and I do like—we can draw this, putting newer commits towards the right and older ones towards the left, like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here `H` stands in for the "h"ash ID of the *last* commit in the chain.  Commit `H` has a full snapshot of all files, plus some metadata, and the metadata *in* commit `H` contains the hash ID of earlier commit `G`.  So `H` *points to* `G`, as represented by the little arrow sticking backwards out o `H`.

This means that if we can get Git the hash ID of commit `H`, Git can use commit `H` to *find* earlier commit `G`.  Of course, `G` is an ordinary commit too, so it has the one arrow sticking out of it, pointing backwards to its parent `F`.  Git can now find commit `F`.  As long as this, too, is an ordinary commit, it points backwards to yet another commit.

In this manner, Git can find *every* commit in a chain, as long as Git can find the *last* commit in the chain.  All we have to do is memorize the hash ID of our *last* commits.  Of course, memorizing `9bf691b78-ugh-glah-whatever` is horribly painful, so Git gives us a way to avoid that.

---

<sup>1</sup>We can prove mathematically that this idea is doomed to failure.  The sheer size of the hash ID space, however, puts the date of failure far enough into the future that—we hope—we will never have to care.

---

#### Branch names find the *last* commits

To avoid having to memorize the hash ID of commit `H`, we simply tell Git that we'd like to have a *branch name*, such as `master`.  Git sticks the *last* hash ID into the name:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
```

The name now *points to* the last commit, from which Git can find every earlier commit.  That's all there is to it—well, *almost* all.

As I mentioned earlier, Git likes us to be "on" a branch.  Being on some branch means that the special name `HEAD` is *attached to* the branch name: that's how Git knows which of our many branch names we're actually using.

Let's add a new branch name now, and make it also point to commit `H`, like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- development, master (HEAD)
```

This means we're "on" `master`.  Both *names* select commit `H`, and commit `H` is the commit we're *using right now*, but we're doing that *using the name `master`*.

If we run `git switch development` now, we get:

```
...--G--H   <-- development (HEAD), master
```

We're still using commit `H`, but now we're doing so *through the name `development`*.  This matters when we create a *new* commit.  Because we're using commit `H`, our new commit will point backwards *to* `H`, but the hash ID *of that new commit* will get saved away in the *current branch name*, like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I   <-- development (HEAD)
```

If we make another new commit now, this new commit `J` will point backwards to `I`—because we're on commit `I` now, through name `development`—and Git will update the name `development` again:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- development (HEAD)
```

This is how branches grow, in Git.  Should we switch back to `master` now:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          I--J   <-- development
```

Git will *take away* the `development`, i.e., commit-`J`, files, and put back all the commit-`H` files instead.

#### Git's index and your working tree

I mentioned (briefly) that Git's commits are read-only, and the files are stored *in* the commit in a sort of archive fashion, with compression and de-duplication.  What this means for us is that we literally *can't* read those files—only Git can *read* them—and literally nothing, not even Git itself, can overwrite them.  That's great for archival—which is what the commits are doing, at least at the first level—but useless for getting any *new work* done.

To get work done, then, Git has to *un-archive* the files in a commit.  When we switch around, with `git switch` or `git checkout`, Git will extract all the files *from* the commit we're moving to.  First, of course, Git has to *remove* all the files we're moving away-from.  Then Git extracts all the files somewhere that you can work.  That's your *working tree* or *work-tree*.  You can now get work done!

Git's de-duplication trick comes into play here.  Removing and replacing files is kind of slow, so Git *checks*, before switching from commit to commit, *which files are duplicates*.  For those files, Git doesn't have to do anything at all—and then it doesn't.  And, if we are switching from, say, commit `H` to commit `H`, that means *every file is a duplicate* and therefore Git does not have to remove-and-replace *any files*.

That's why creating a new branch name, then switching to it, is safe here.  No files need to be reworked; no files need to be touched at all.  So Git touches no files, and all is well.

There's more to say about this, though.  Often, Git *does* have to fill in the working tree.  Consider, for instance, the case where you have just cloned a repository and Git is filling in your working tree for the first time ever.  You might think: *Ah, well, Git just extracts all the files.*  That's what other version control systems do, for instance.  It would be sufficient.  But that's not what Git does.

Instead, Git has a kind of tracking system for files, that Git calls by three names: the *index*, the *staging area*, and sometimes (mostly now in flags like `git rm --cached`) the *cache*.  These three names all refer to the same thing.

When Git is extracting a commit, Git fills in its index *and* your working tree with the files from that commit.  The copy (or "copy" perhaps) in the index is pre-de-duplicated, stored in Git's internal read-only format, but unlike the copy in a commit—which is frozen for as long as the commit itself continues to exist—the index copy *can* be replaced wholesale.  Since the initial copy (or "copy") *is* a duplicate—of whatever is in the commit—it's automatically de-duplicated away to almost nothing.  (The index entry itself still takes some space, to hold the file's name and a bunch of cache data.)

Again, this index *is* the "staging area": these are two names for the same thing.  When you modify a working-tree copy of a file, *nothing happens* to the index copy—not yet!  It just sits there, still holding the de-duplicated duplicate from the commit.

When you run `git add`, though, Git reads the working tree copy of the file, compresses it into the internal format that Git uses in commits, and checks for duplicates.  If the compressed file would be a duplicate, Git throws out the compressed copy it just built and uses instead the existing compressed copy.  Otherwise, it saves away the compressed copy it just made.  In either case, Git now swaps that *new-or-re-used* copy/"copy" into the index.<sup>2</sup>

The result of all this is simple:

- before `git add`, the index held a copy of every file (pre-de-duplicated), ready to commit;
- after `git add`, the index still holds a copy of every file (pre-de-duplicated), ready to commit.

This means that *at all times*, the index holds a copy of every file, ready to commit.  **In effect, the index holds the snapshot for your proposed *next* commit.**

When you run `git commit`, Git just packages up all the files that are in the index, in the form they have right then, to be used in the new snapshot.  This will be the archive for the new commit.  Git also gathers or generates the necessary metadata at this point—using the *current commit hash ID* as the parent—and writes all of this out to obtain the new commit's random-looking hash ID, and then `git commit` stores the new commit into the database and stuffs its ID into the current branch name.

It's all really relatively simple.  So where do *changes* come in?

---

<sup>2</sup>Technically, the index entry holds the file's name, some cache data, and a *blob hash ID* for an object in the all-objects database.  You don't really need to worry about this.  You can think of the index as holding a full copy, if you prefer.

---

#### If a commit is a snapshot, why do we see changes?

If you run `git show` on an ordinary commit, Git will:

1. spit out the metadata; then
2. show a *diff* to show you what changed.

Git *computes* this diff at this time!  Git uses the metadata in that ordinary commit to find the commit's parent.  Git then extracts *both snapshots* (to a temporary area, in memory really) and compares the de-duplicated files.  Since the duplicates are now trivial to spot, Git really only has to compare the *differing* files.  For each such file, Git computes a set of changes that, if applied to the parent's copy of the file, would produce the child's copy of that file.

That's the diff you see: the one `git diff` just made by comparing a parent to a child.  (The `git show` command invokes the same internal code as `git diff` for this.  It's just that `git show` automatically locates the parent for you.  If you want to use `git diff` this way, you have to pick out both commits.  The upside of having to pick out both commits is that you can pick out *any* pair of commits.)

When you run `git status`, Git:

- prints stuff about the current branch first (`On branch master` for instance);
- runs a `git diff` to compare the *current commit* snapshot to the *index* snapshot; and
- runs one more `git diff`.

That first comparison—what's changed between the current commit, and the proposed next snapshot in the index / staging-area—can quickly skip over the de-duplicated identical files, and compare just the *different* files.  Since it's not going to emit an actual set of changes, it short-circuits that code—you can do this yourself with `git diff --name-status`—and shows just that some file is *changed*.

Any file that shows up here as changed is listed under *changes staged for commit*.  New files, or deleted files, here, show up the same way.  (Git also does rename detection here; we won't cover this properly.)

Having listed these "staged for commit" files, `git status` is done with the first diff.  It now goes on to do a second `git diff --name-status`, this time comparing what's in its index to what's in your working tree.<sup>3</sup>  For each file that's the same, once again, Git says nothing.  But for files that are different, Git now mentions the file's name, and lists this file under *changes not staged for commit*.

There's a bit of weirdness here though.  Suppose you delete a file from your working tree, without deleting it from Git's index, using your OS's "remove a file" command (whatever that is for your OS).  Git will say that a deletion of this file is "not staged for commit".  That makes sense, and matches the first kind of diff: if you use `git rm`, which removes *both* the index *and* the working tree copy, you see the deletion as "staged for commit" (and then the index and working tree lack-of-copy matches, so it's not mentioned again).

But suppose you have an *all-new file* that you have not `git add`-ed, in your working tree.  Git saves these file names for after the diff output.  It then goes on to whine about these files as being *untracked*.

---

<sup>3</sup>Since the files in your working tree *aren't* compressed-and-de-duplicated—they're just ordinary files—Git has to work a lot harder here.  We'll skip all these details too.

---

#### Untracked files and `.gitignore`

**An *untracked file* is a file that is in your working tree, but not in Git's index.**  That's all there is to this, except for the fact that the index is something you (partially) control, with `git add` and `git rm`.  It's crucial that you understand this, because of some weirdness with `.gitignore`.

The `.gitignore` file is rather misnamed.  This doesn't *ignore* a file.  Git commits whatever is in Git's index: you run `git commit`, whatever is in Git's index goes into the new commit.  What `.gitignore` does starts with this: it makes `git status` *shut up*.

When you run `git status`, it whines a lot about all your build files, for instance.  But they are untracked *on purpose*, and we want them to stay that way.  Complaining about them is counterproductive.  So listing those in `.gitignore` tells Git: *shut the ____ up*.

The `git add` command also has some en-masse "add everything" modes: e.g., `git add .` or `git add --all`.  These look for all the files that Git *would* complain about, and adds them.  Since listing the files in `.gitignore` makes Git stop complaining, it also makes Git stop adding those files, if they're currently untracked.

What `.gitignore` *doesn't* do is stop Git from committing the files when they're tracked.  If some file is in Git's index, it *will* be committed.  The "add all" or `git add -u` (update) modes will update the index copy from the working tree copy.  So this should be called `.git-do-not-complain-about-these-files-when-they-are-untracked-and-do-not-add-them-with-an-en-masse-git-add-operation-either`, or something.  But nobody wants to type in a file name like that, so `.gitignore` it is.

#### Conclusion

Once you know *what the index is and does* and *how Git swaps out index and working tree copies when you change commits*, it becomes clear that as long as you *don't* change commits—such as, when you create a new branch that still selects the *current* commit, and then switch to that branch—it's quite safe to just make a new commit on a new branch by making the new branch first.

(Later, once you understand how branch names "point to" commits, it's easy to see how to make a commit, then create a branch name, then move the other branch name *back* one step, to achieve the same thing.  But that's more work, so you might as well do the simpler and clearer thing.)

Comment: Best information to understand the internals on how git is actually working. And probably one of the longest answers on SO :)-